# Using Monero as a payment source for my business

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-integration, payment, payment-provider

I've been thinking about the best way to handle payments in a business I want to start. My first thought was Bitcoin, but after doing quite a bit of reading on Monero, I think that would be the best option.

I don't want to transfer the Monero into my local currency. I want to keep it as Monero for as long as possible.

Is it possible to have a different payment address for each registered use?

Is there anything else I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [subaddress](https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/)

Comment: Awesome. That seems to be what I am looking for. So from my understanding, you can create multiple accounts, and each of those accounts can have various subaddresses?

Comment: @Cromulent Yes. Exactly.